# SwiftでArrayの中から1種類づつを抽出したい。

Tags: swift

お世話になっております。
表題の通りですが、Arrayの中から下記のようにデータを抽出するにはどうしたら良いのか？を教えていただきたいです。

Apple
Apple
Google
Google
Facebook
Facebook
Apple
Google
Facebook
Apple
Google
Apple

という配列を
Apple
Google
Facebook
という配列に変換したいです。

一番目のAppleと２番目のStringを比較してAppleと同じであれば消去。
違っていればスルー。
一番目のAppleと3番目のStringを比較して同じであれば消去。
違っていればスルー・・・。
という具合に比較して、順番に数を減らして行き最終的に、
Apple
Google
Facebook
という配列に変換したいです。

下記のようのコードを途中まで作ってみたのですが、比較する回数、11回のはずですがそれが違うようです。
そもそも11回にならない理由がわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

> var strArray = ["Apple", "Apple", "Google","Google", "Facebook",
>   "Facebook","Apple", "Google", "Facebook","Apple", "Google","Apple"]
>   var c = strArray.count - 1
>   var x:Int = 0 
>   var z:Int = 0 
>   if c > 2 {
>       for i in 1...c{        
>           if strArray[x] == strArray[x + z] {
>               strArray.removeAtIndex(x + z)        
>           }        
>           z = z + 1
>           print(strArray)
>       　} 
>   }

Comment: 処理途中でIndex out of rangeで異常終了すると思います。`for i in 1...c {`の行の直後に`print(c,x,z,strArray.count)`を追加して、各変数がどのように変化していくかを確認すると良いと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

元の配列の順序が維持されないかもしれませんが、別解です。

```
var strArray = ["Apple", "Apple", "Google","Google", "Facebook",
    "Facebook","Apple", "Google", "Facebook","Apple", "Google","Apple"]
strArray = Array(Set(strArray))
```

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。出来ました。有難うございました。

Answer (score 1):

NSOrderedSetを用いる方法があります。

```
let values = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "2nd"]
let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: values)
let uniqueValues = orderedSet.array as! [String]
//["1st", "2nd", "3rd"]
```

しかしこの方法では、AnyObjectに限定されてしまう点とas!を利用してしまうという問題点があります。
[Unique values of array in swift [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624331/unique-values-of-array-in-swift)ではArrayを拡張して`unique()`を使う方法と`Set`を利用する方法が紹介されてます。

Comment: 早々のご回答有難うございます。お陰様で解決しました。有難うございます。

Comment: 重ねて質問させて下さい。実は通常のArrayではなく、RealmSwiftのデータを読みだして、それをUITableViewに表示をするのが目的でやってます。今回教わった方法はString型ではなくArray型のようで、そのままTableViewにそのままではいれられないようです。Array型をString型に変換する必要があるようです。ネットで調べてみましたが、これといった情報はヒットしませんでした。もし変換する方法をご存知でしたらお教え願えませんか？